# button design with overflow

Tags: html, css, button

[image: button design]

hey i'm trying to create a fancy button, but the problem is i can't get my text to over lay.

because this reason i can't get a example, is there anyone with suggestions.

```css
.btnStyle{
    border: none;
    background-color: #EB343D ;
    color: #FFFFFF ;
    
    &:after{
        content: " ";
        padding: 10px 
    }
    &:before{
        content: " ";
    }
    span{
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" class="btnStyle"><span>Click here</span></button>
```

when i use a position absolute on the span i hoped the item would be absolute on the btn.

Answer (score 0):

[click to run the program](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/873581/)

```
enter code here Html
<button type="button" name="button" class="btnStyle"><span>Click here</span></button>

css
.btnStyle{
    border: none;
    background-color: #EB343D ;
    color: #FFFFFF ;
    }
    .btnStyle:after{
        content: " ";
        padding: 10px 
    }
    .btnStyle:before{
        content: " ";
    }
    span{
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a image on the top for what i'm trying to accomplish. i want to red to expand on hover and the text on de edge of the button.

I'm still a student learning to code.

Answer (score 0):

- Move `span` out from the `.btnStyle`
- And change it to `position: relative` with a relative top value. (However the clickable area will be only the red rectangle...)
- Added black background...

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.btnStyle {
  border: none;
  background-color: #EB343D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    padding: 10px
  }
  &:before {
    content: " ";
  }
}

.btnStyle span {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" class="btnStyle"><span>Click here</span></button>
```

Another version could be a single pixel wide PNG that is transparent above, and red below, and is used as the background...